# Unittest for click module

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-click

I wrote a simple command line utility that accepts a text file and searches for a given word in it using the click module.

**sfind.py**

```
import click
@click.command()
@click.option('--name', prompt='Word or string')
@click.option('--filename', default='file.txt', prompt='file name')
@click.option('--param', default=1, prompt="Use 1 for save line and 2 for word, default: ")
def find(name, filename, param):
    """Simple program that find  word or string at text file and put it in new"""
    try:
        with open(filename) as f, open('result.txt', 'w') as f2:
            count = 0
            for line in f:
                if name in line:
                    if param == 1:
                        f2.write(line + '\n')
                    elif param == 2:
                        f2.write(name + '\n')
                    count += 1
            print("Find: {} sample".format(count))
            return count
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('WARNING! ' + 'File: ' + filename + ' not found')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    find()
```

Now I need to write a test using unittest (using unittest is required).

**test_sfind.py**

```
import unittest
import sfind

class SfindTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sfind(self):
        self.assertEqual(sfind.find(), 4)


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test:

```
python -m unittest test_sfind.py
```

I get an error

> click.exceptions.UsageError: Got unexpected extra argument (test_sfind.py)

How can I test this click command?

Comment: You have to [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) `sys.argv` for the test.

Comment: Is it possible using only true unittest without the use any other libraries?

Comment: I think the correct way to run it is `python -m unittest test_sfind.SfindTest`

Comment: I tried this method but the exact same error

Comment: Ah ok...but you're not passing any argument to your `find()` function, whereas it takes 3...

Comment: A "true" unit test tests the unit and mocks all dependencies. Is that what you mean? And what makes the difference between the `mock` and the `unittest` package?

Comment: @toti08 If I change to `self.assertEqual(sfind.find(name='and', filename='text.txt', param=1), 4)` exact error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: I think you shouldn't specify `name='and'`, but just pass `'and'`, as yours are not keyword arguments...

Comment: @toti08 do it, but now `Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (a n d) exact` ((

Comment: By calling `self.assertEqual(sfind.find('and', 'text.txt', 1),4)`?

Comment: @KlausD.  
I mistakenly thought that for mock you need to do an additional installation of pip install ...

Comment: @toti08 yes, exactly

Comment: @lepiloff sorry, my bad, I think you shouldn't pass arguments to your function after all...

Comment: `mock`was an external library, but has been adopted into standard library.

Comment: Have you thought about adding your parameters to `sys.argv`?

Comment: @toti08, No, unfortunately I didnt know how this can help me

Comment: Maybe [this](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/testing/) piece of documentation can help you. They do testing, but without using the `unittest` framework...

Comment: @toti08 Yes, I read it, but I only need to use unittest, and this is the problem of making friends with unittest and click. Unittest is not my whim, but a condition

Comment: @KlausD. 
May be  you can write sample code using mock to test my function?

Answer (score 12):

You can not simply call a click command and then expect it to return.  The decorators applied to make a click command considerably change the behavior of the function.  Fortunately the click frameworks provides for this through the [`CliRunner`](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/testing/) class.

Your command can be tested via unittest with something like this:

```
import unittest
import sfind
from click.testing import CliRunner

class TestSfind(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sfind(self):

        runner = CliRunner()
        result = runner.invoke(
            sfind.find, '--name url --filename good'.split(), input='2')
        self.assertEqual(0, result.exit_code)
        self.assertIn('Find: 3 sample', result.output)
```

Comment: I try this, unexpected extra argument error disappeared. But result -     `self.assertEqual(0, result.exit_code)
AssertionError: 0 != 1`

Comment: That means your code under test had an error.  Inspect the `result` for the error message.

Comment: What should I replace this code with:` --name url --filename good'.split()` ?

Comment: That is what is passed in.  Basically that is what would normally be in the list `sys.argv`.  So what do you want to send in to test your program?  Put it there.

Comment: Then I added print(result) before self.assert I saw an error in the console `<Result TypeError("find() got multiple values for argument 'name'",)>`

Comment: So your command line is wrong.  Sounds like the testing is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

For those wanting to test exceptions in a click command, I have found this way to do it:

```py
def test_download_artifacts(
        self,
    ):
        runner = CliRunner()
        # test exception raised for invalid dir format
        result = runner.invoke(
            my_module.download_artifacts,
            '--bucket_name my_bucket \
            --artifact_dir artifact_dir'.split(),
            input='2')
        print(f"result.exception: {result.exception}")
        assert "Enter artifact_dir ending" in str(result.exception)
```